# Estimating the effects of cumulative odds ratios - additive or exponential?

Tags: logistic, odds-ratio, logarithm

I have run some regression models that examine the effect of variable X (a 15 point continuous scale) on Y (a binary variable - not perform/perform a particular behaviour) using logistic regression.

For the sake of this example, let’s say that the OR in one of the models is 1.08. I can argue that for each extra exposure on scale X, the respondents are 8% more likely to do Y. So far, so good.

The average score on the X scale is 7. I originally considered that somebody with an average score on the X scale (7) was 56% more likely to do Y (7 x 8%) than somebody with a 0 score on the X scale. However, I have been told that this is incorrect – that the correct calculation is 1.08 to the power of 7 (= 1.71), or in other words that they are 71% more likely to do Y if they have an average score on X compared to somebody who has a 0 score on X.

Cam anybody confirm (1) that this is correct and (2) provide a good reference for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's additive on the log scale.

The natural log of your odds ratio is 0.7696 (this should be the estimate from your model). As such, the odds ratio of going from 0 to 7 is exp(0.07696*7) = exp(0.53872) = 1.71

Comment: Basic properties of $\exp$ and $\log$ imply $\exp(\log(1.08)\times 7)$ should be identical to $1.08^7 \approx 1.71,$ disagreeing with this answer but agreeing with the question.

Comment: @whuber The "answer" is right - what's wrong is the rounding. Correcting it now. I blame the journal I'm currently revising a submission for, which is making me lop off all manner of precision.

Comment: Many thanks for this. Do either of you know a reference I could use to back this up?

Comment: @Benincasa How 'citable' a reference are you looking for? Book/journal or website?

Comment: @EpiGrad - whatever you have! Preferably a book or journal, but a website would suffice in the absence of a higher quality source.

Comment: @Benincasa http://books.google.com/books?id=GSvV9-71AfUC&pg=PA193&lpg=PA193&dq=logistic+regression+additive+on+the+log+scale&source=bl&ots=j_-4db52xV&sig=egIej2Xe8yjH6L-t34g5wU1LVFI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Uk1xUpynBPPMsASFgoGwBQ&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=logistic%20regression%20additive%20on%20the%20log%20scale&f=false Sources about for google search for "logistic regression additive on the log scale"